# derivative of composite function to 'fourth degree'

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

> Question: What is the derivative of $\left ( \varphi ' \circ \varphi^{-1} \right )\circ \left ( \varphi\circ f \right )$?

This came up in a proof and evidently at the scope of my study, this is more a hassle than anything.

I'm looking for an answer, not a hint as I'm no longer at the level where I dabble with these supposedly elementary stuffs.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean 4th degree?

Comment: Hint: functional composition is associative. What happens if you compose a function with its inverse?

Comment: The paragraph about being "no longer at the level" is unclear. Are you saying you don't want to work this out yourself because it's too easy?

Comment: It is unecessarily tedious if anything. The composition of a function with a function is 'doable'. Anything beyond that is unecessarily tedious-I take a black box approach.

Comment: @Aydin Greek 'fourth degree'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an extension of the chain rule
$$
(a∘b∘c∘d)'=(a'∘b∘c∘d)·(b'∘c∘d)·(c'∘d)·(d')
$$

---

As 
$$(ψ^{−1}∘a)'=(ψ'∘ψ^{−1}∘a)^{−1}·a'$$ 
because of by chain rule
$$a'=(ψ∘ψ^{−1}∘a)'=(ψ'∘ψ^{−1}∘a)·(ψ^{−1}∘a)',$$ 
your expression becomes
$$
(ψ'∘ψ^{−1}∘φ∘f)'=(ψ''∘ψ^{−1}∘φ∘f)·(ψ'∘ψ^{−1}∘φ∘f)^{−1}·(φ'∘f)·(f'),
$$
renaming the first two functions to avoid the cancellation of the terms in the middle.